# Looping through dictionaries in a list to find sum of values from matching keys. (Counting Votes)

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I am having trouble getting counter to work. What Im trying to do is get a vote count. keys are the names of candidates, values are number of votes. Collect that info from user input, and print out final tally of votes per candidate.

```
from collections import Counter

name_vote =[]
count = int(input('How many?'))

while count >=1: 
    a=input('Name')
    b=input('Vote')
    c={ a:b }
    name_vote.append(c)
    count = count - 1

print(name_vote)

c = Counter()
for d in name_vote:
    c.update(d)

print(c)
```

user tells first how many vote inputs there are (this is count)

So input look like this:
How many? = 6

John 2

Bill 5

John 4

Scott 11

John 3

Scott 1

**Result: (Print out)**

John 9

Bill 5

Scott 12

Very new at this and really appreciate the help. Tried to look up solution in others posts, that's where I found using counter. But is not working in my code. Produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Rghol5212/hello/Dico.py", line 30, in <module>
    c.update(d)
  File "C:\Users\Rghol5212\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
 32\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 649, in update
    self[elem] = count + self_get(elem, 0)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you're building the dictionary, it would be better to recognize when the input name is the same as a previous name and add that person's new votes to their old votes, instead of making a completely new dict with the same name key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) instead. If the name does not exist in the dictionary, a default value of zero will be used. If the name exists, the votes will just increase the count.

```
from collections import defaultdict

name_vote = defaultdict(int)

count = int(input('How many?'))

while count >=1: 
    a=input('Name')
    b=input('Vote')
    name_vote[a] = name_vote[a] + int(b)
    count = count - 1

for k,v in name_vote.items():
    print("{} {}".format(k,v))
```

Comment: thank you very much ! i knew there was some kind of function that would do this exact job. I appreciate it.

Comment: @TinFoil_Helmet No worries. Consider upvoting as well if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

name_vote = Counter()

count = int(input('How many? '))

while count >= 1:
    name = input('Name ')
    vote = int(input('Vote '))
    name_vote += {name: vote}
    count -= 1

for name, cnt in name_vote.items():
    print("Name: {}, Vote: {}".format(name, cnt))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure the problem is in the line`b=input('Vote')`. When you get `b`from the input, its type is`string`, you need to change it into `int`, so the numbers can be added. Try it by adding  one line of code`b=int(b)`.